# Android KSOAP2 request to PHP SOAP server

Tags: java, php, android, soap, ksoap2

I am trying to create a SOAP client in my android app. I have already tested the server with php SOAP client, and it has been working. But in my android app I am still getting exceptions. Can anyone help me whats wrong and how to fix it? Thanks

PHP

```
<?php
class service
{      
public function service()
{   }

public function login($nickname, $password)
{   

    $sql = "select nick from user 
    where 
    nick =\"$nick\"
    and
    pass = \"$password\"";

    if (($result = $this->db->query($sql)) && ($result->num_rows == 1))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}  
}

$server = new SoapServer(null, array(
'uri' => "urn://www.domain.cz",
'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2)
);              
$server->setClass("service");     
$server->handle(); 
?>
```

Android

```
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.domain.cz/server/server.php";
    private static String NAMESPACE = "urn://www.domain.cz";
    //need fix namespace to work, final solution
    // private static String NAMESPACE = "http://www.domain.cz/server/";
    private static String METHOD_NAME = "login";
    private static String URL = "http://www.domain.cz";

public void Connect()
{
    //Initialize soap request + add parameters
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    //Use this to add parameters
    request.addProperty("nick","peter");
    request.addProperty("password","somepassword");

    //Declare the version of the SOAP request
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    //Needed to make the internet call
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
            //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);//HERE is xmlpullparserexception after a while
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

    if(result != null){
            TextView t = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.resultbox);

            //Get the first property and change the label text
            t.setText("SOAP response:\n\n" + result.getProperty(0).toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the _exact_ exception you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL should be the soap endpoint, i.e. `http://www.domain.cz/server/server.php`

Your SOAP_ACTION should contain the method name, i.e. `http://www.domain.cz/server/server.php/login`

Answer (score 0):

You are using KSOAP(?) I presumed. I think you need to point URL to the web-service path. I see no WSDL at your URL.

Comment: Yes I am using KSOAP. I thought that I can use it without WSDFL file. If KSOAP cant work without WSDL, is there another way?